# iOS app working on iPhone(12.4.5) but not on iPad (13.3.1)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, storyboard, ipad-mini

Here is my problem: I have an iOS app under development. It runs fine on my iPhone 6 with iOS 12.4.5. When I want to run it on an iPad Mini with iOS 13.3.1; I get this in the debugging console of Xcode (Version 11.3.1):

```
2020-03-02 ... *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',
reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'Main' in bundle NSBundle
</private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5...1/MyApp.app> (loaded)'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1824e8a48 0x18220ffa4 ..... 0x1822ea360)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Does is make some sense to anyone?

It says "Could not find a storyboard ....". Indeed I have removed the storyboard, because I don't want it and this is no problem on my iPhone. Do I need to check (or do) something more to make it work on the iPad?

For information, here is the relevant code in the AppDelegate, in case it may be useful.

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder,UIApplicationDelegate,   UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:
        [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        let navigatCtrlr = UINavigationController(), topVC = ViewController()
        navigatCtrlr.viewControllers = [topVC]
        navigatCtrlr.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.darkGray
        window!.rootViewController = navigatCtrlr
        window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
        .....

        return true
    }
    .....
}
```

Beside, the Main storyboard has been removed from the Info.plist

Comment: grep Main.storyboard .

Comment: Check your info.plist and look for "Main storyboard". Also, it might help if you were to post the code in your app delegate.

Comment: No. I have already cleaned an rebuilt the app many times and it keeps working on the iPhone. Deleting the Main.storyboard is actually something I commonly do with my iPhone apps.

Comment: @Rob. I edited the post to add the code you are interested in.

Comment: Did you create this project with Xcode 11? My guess is that you did, and you don't realize that Main.storyboard is mentioned in the Info.plist _twice_. Do a global search, you'll find it.

Comment: The reason I ask about the Info.plist is because you can define different storyboard for the iPhone and the iPad. I'm willing to bet you still have an iPad storyboard property lingering there.

Comment: In fact, you appear to be right. Even though I had removed the Main.storyboard in the Info.plist when erasing the storyboard from the app. After taking another look I found something inside the Scene stuff. After removing all that, it worked. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Not “anyway”. That is exactly what I was getting at.

Comment: You're right, not “anyway” but “thisway”. After rereading you comment I also figured out this is what you had in mind. That's why I "upped it".